# How to read a xml file stored in a application local folder in windows phone 8.1 app development

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am new in windows application development.I am looking for code which help me to read the content of xml file stored in the application local folder.

Description : In my application once user clicks on the submit button,I have stored the user status as "true" in xml file using below code :
//

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var stream = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(FILENAME, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

Usercontent +=signup_Username.Text;
Usercontent += signup_Number.Text;
Usercontent += signup_Email.Text;
Usercontent += signup_Password.Password;
Usercontent += "\n LoginStatus : " + true + "";

await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(stream, Usercontent);
```

But once the user again enter in my application I want to check the user status whether `true` or `false` by reading this above created file content.
This is offline process to check the logged in status in a local mobile.

Platform - Windows phone 8.1
XAML and C#

Can you please someone help me to implement this functionality.

Comment: For storing short information like the one you have in your code, I would suggest to use *Settings* - very good [help is at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx). Though for password I would use [*PasswordVault*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465069.aspx). If you want to stick with files - (as you have saved some information) you will have to open file, read it and parse the saved string - [about reading/writing you will find some help at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx).